# IPDU transmission from PDUR to specific bus interface

Tags: can-bus, autosar, pdu

I am totally new to autosar and while going through the documents i have a doubt

So, when PDUR recieves signal from upper layer how will it seggregate and send them to specific bus interface module say CANIF, LINIF. How will it get to know which IPDU needs to be send via CAN and LIN? Similarly while recieving

Answer (score 1):

PduR is not receiving/sending signals directly, it only handles I-PDUs. It is the COM module's responsibility to wrap/unwrap between signals/PDUs.

As Uwe mentioned in his answer it depends on the ECU Config which PDU will be routed towards which physical interface. Think of PDU Router runtime as a static routing table, built upon the configuration values.
I circled for you with orange the exit points towards lower, bus-dependent layers. PduR treats multiplexed, secured or container PDUs differently, sending them not "down" but "up" on the diagram below.

[image]

You can figure out where exactly an I-PDU will be forwarded by searching for config elements of type `PduRRoutingPath`. You will find them under the 'PduR' config module. Depending on the exact AUTOSAR version you will find at least two  reference parameters called like 'dest' and 'source' pointing to PDU descriptions.

- One of the referenced PDUs will have another referee in a
  configuration Module with a name like 'CanIf' or 'FrIf'. Now you know
  which interface its heading to or coming from.
- If not, then your signal can be in a container or secured I-PDU. Then you need some
  further digging in the config, as the `PduRRoutingPath` you find will
  have its other reference pointing to an I-PDU defined in SecOC or IpduM configuration Modules.

I-PDUs of the latter types are not leaving/entering the ECU in their plain format. The router routes such I-PDUs "up" to corresponding modules for processing.

Such wrappings can even be chained: a signal PDU can be multiplexed and encoded at the same time. In this case, a transmit signal's data would do multiple in and outs on the top of the PDU Router, before the payload actually leaves thru one of the bottom exits I circled.

Comment: Can you please provide me the AUTOSAR Document Name where the picture of AUTOSAR Software Stack as shown above is provided?

Comment: @user3806728 Specification of Socket Adaptor, Document-ID: 416. Chapter 1 Introduction and functional overview.

Answer (score 0):

The routes are defined in the ECU Configuration model (EcuC) of the PduR. The code of the PduR is typically generated from that model.

Answer (score 0):

PDUR have the routing table, there we will be configuring the source and destination for each message. example: consider you have one can message which you need to transmit to application component, then in PDUR routing table source of the will be configured with the CANIF reference of particular message similarly destination will be configured with the Upper layer that is COM. with help of RTE data will be sent to the application.

similarly for other protocols (LIN) messages also souce and destination path will be configured in the PDUR.